# Is it possible to mount multiple volumes when starting minikube?

Tags: kubernetes, minikube

I tried this but didn't work:

```
minikube start --vm-driver=hyperkit --memory 8192 --mount \
               --mount-string /home/user/app1:/minikube-host/app1 \
               --mount-string /home/user/app2:/minikube-host/app2
```

but only `/home/user/app2` was mounted.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can run multiple `mount` commands after starting your `minikube` to mount the different folders:

```
minikube mount /home/user/app1:/minikube-host/app1
minikube mount /home/user/app2:/minikube-host/app2
```

This will mount multiple folders in minikube .

Comment: Thanks Prafull, I managed to do that, but was wondering if the `minikube start` command would let me do that.

Comment: No, as the command line argument has only one `--mount-string` type argument. If you provide two `--mount-string` then it will take the later one. As the argument parser doesn't have any way to identify that they are two different inputs provided by user

Comment: from my experience the `minikube mount` command is less table than the `minikube start --mount`. When used it I often had to restart the whole minikube instance because files could not be read.

Answer (score 2):

There is no need for multiple volumes when starting in your case.

Also, minikube mount after start needs a terminal in running state(opened always).

You can mount `/home/user -> /minikube-host`. All the folders inside `/home/user` will be inside VM at `/minikube-host`.

- `/home/user/app1` will be available inside VM as
  `/minikube-host/app1`
- `/home/user/app2` will be available inside VM as
  `/minikube-host/app2`

  minikube start --vm-driver=hyperkit --memory 8192 --mount \
                 --mount-string /home/user:/minikube-host

Hope this helps !

Answer (score 0):

Currently there is no way. Even using "minikube mount" you need to run each command in separate terminal, what is completely unusable

Comment: You can run all mount commands in the same terminal. The only criterium is that the "minikube mount" process has to be running. If you put the commands in the background, the terminal can be reused to start other commands. Also, when started with "nohup", the process will be detached from their controlling terminal, so you can even close the terminal without causing the processes to get terminated. The bigger problem is of course that the pods may expect the mounts to be available "early"...

Comment: This really is quite shoddy, as with numerous other features I've encountered with Minikube in the short time I've been using it. It should at least have an option to self daemonize.

Comment: I ran the "minikube mount" as background processes, so I can issue multiple mount commands in the same terminal. In Linux, add " &" at the end of each "minikube mount" command. In Windows, add "start /b " before each "minikube mount" command.